# Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier openCV for tree crown detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, object-detection, haar-classifier

I'd like to build tree crown detection software using OpenCV. Is it a good approach to do it using Haar-feature based Cascade Classifier?
The tree crown I'd like to detect is oil palm trees.
A sample of some images of the trees is below:
[image: palm trees]

Is it doable if I use Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier in OpenCV?

Comment: What have you tried?  How many positive images of these trees can you generate/acquire?  Assuming you can acquire enough images of both these trees and `other trees that will also be in the area`, I believe you should be able to detect these.

Comment: @JohnAllen  I've tried to detect the crown using HSV thresholding and blob analysis, but it worked poorly when the images contain a lot of grass (which is have same color to the tree crown). The positive images i can acquire probably between 500 and 900 is it good enough ?

Comment: Is it good enough depends on how similar the other trees are to your type of tree.  I would look at OpenCV's object detection.  I wrote a tutorial here: johnallen.github.io/opencv-object-detection-tutorial